# Is there a way to get fragment from top of stack?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a ListFragment in my MainActivity. Here is how I set my fragment object.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment newFragment = new MyFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framecontainer, newFragment, "tag");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The problem is when the user press back button, I have to, at least, change the action bar and menu by calling

```
getActionBar().setTitle(title);
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(isEnabled);
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

I have to know what kind of fragment is showing currently, so that I know how to set the action bar. I store the setting option in fragment as arguments.

```
String title = fragment.getArguments().getString("KEY_TITLE");
boolean isEnabled = fragment.getArguments().getBoolean("KEY_ISENABLED");
```

I do search the related question, and I realized I could get the fragment by calling

```
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentByTag("tag");
```

However, I have to store all the tag in a custom stack, and call **pop()** everytime when user pressed back button in `onBackPressed()`.

So, my question is that ***is there a way for me to get the current visible fragment from the stack directly?***

Note: Please keep in mind that the fragment types are different, not just only MyFragment.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Some thing like this should help your activity figure this out on backpress:

```
private Fragment getCurrentFragment(){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    String fragmentTag = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
    Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
    return currentFragment;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragmentBeforeBackPress = getCurrentFragment();
    // Perform the usual back action
    super.onBackPressed();
    Fragment fragmentAfterBackPress = getCurrentFragment();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems that if I do it in your way, I have to set **fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag)** as well; Otherwise, I would get a NullPointerException. So **fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();** is not refer to tag name

Comment: Yea...you will have to check for nulls and bad math ((getBackStackEntryCount-1) > 0 and such).  I kinda wrote this too quickly. Also,  fragements added without a tag will come up as null.

Comment: @umerk44  You have to account for backstack names that are null in your `getCurrentFragment` implementation.  I prefer to use a string name  to avoid `instanceof` type detections and find it most helpful whenin debugging--doing a backstack walk/loop that prints out the names.

Comment: I think you mixed fragment tagName (used while adding or replacing a fragment) with backstack name (which can only be used to pop the fragment using that name). I wonder if above actually works.

Comment: This is great answer!. Thanks

Answer (score 35):

```
FragmentManager.findFragmentById(fragmentsContainerId)
```

[function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById%28int%29) returns link to top `Fragment` in backstack. Usage example:

```
    fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            Fragment fr = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentsContainer);
            if(fr!=null){
                Log.e("fragment=", f.getClass().getSimpleName());
            }
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:** now in 2018 there is [getFragments](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager#getFragments()) method in `FragmentManager` which return `List<Fragment>`. From docs: `The order of the fragments in the list is the order in which they were added or attached`. So it looks like we can just take last fragment from that list:

```
     List<Fragment> list = fragmentManager.getFragments();
     //get last one 
     Fragment topFragment = list.get(list.size() - 1);
```

Comment: This seems kind of bizarre... but does work great for me :).  The docs do say it searches the backstack, so hopefully it always searches from the top of the stack, in all versions of Android (fingers crossed).

Comment: I have been searching for this for so long. Thanks for clearing up how this listener works

Comment: `getFragments` working for me ! I suggest you put it in top of the comment to get more visibility :)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like something has changed for the better, because code below works perfectly for me, but I didn't find it in already provided answers neither here, nor in neighbour questions.

Kotlin:

```
supportFragmentManager.fragments[supportFragmentManager.fragments.size - 1]
```

Java:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()
.get(getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size() - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already an answer marked as correct and my additional information's will not 
be that different to that. BUT, I got in trouble when using a receiver an trying to
figure out if the fragment from where the receiver is from is the current top 
fragment on the stack. You can easily run in a lot of NPE and Index out of bounds.
Therefore I wrote this, maybe it helps somebody.

```
private boolean isFragmentOnTop(Activity parentActivity, final String fragmentName){
        FragmentManager fmManager = parentActivity.getFragmentManager();
        if(fmManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0){
            LOG.i("BackStack entry count is 0: " + this);
            return false;
        }
        String fragmentNameOnStackTop = "";
        final FragmentManager.BackStackEntry topEntry = fmManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fmManager.getBackStackEntryCount() -1);
        if(topEntry != null) {
            fragmentNameOnStackTop = topEntry.getName();
        }
        LOG.d("Got fragments name: " + fragmentNameOnStackTop);
        return fragmentNameOnStackTop != null ? fragmentNameOnStackTop.equals(fragmentName) : false;
    }
```

Note that this works fine for an activity having some fragments. Be aware if you're 
using ViewPager an childfragmentmanager.

And do not forget to set the fragmentName in `FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentName)`

Answer (score 1):

this helper method get fragment from top of stack:

```
public Fragment getTopFragment() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    String fragmentTag = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
}
```